# How to make the canvas fit the shape of my image?

Tags: gimp, png

I have the following image:

[image]

I would like the canvas fit the exact shape of the room shown on this image. The goal is to include this image on my website and create a little effect whenever someone clicks on this image. The issue so far is that whenever someone clicks on the invisible area around the room, the effect starts as well because the invisible area with grey squares also belongs to the image being exported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea. You can't save your image like that.

---

You could do the clickable areas with [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).

**Image Map example:**

[image]

1. [Example code](https://jsfiddle.net/lollero/u05oop24/)
2. I used this [image map generator](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/) to draw the outlines of the floor plan. You can find many of these types of tools online.

   - Basically you upload the image and click to create points around the shape you want to turn into a clickable area, and repeat that for each shape.
3. Used jquery to switch the `src` of the `img` based on which area was hovered over.

---

Also, you could do it using svg.

**SVG Example:**

[image]

1. [Example code](https://jsfiddle.net/lollero/u05oop24/1/)
2. Brought the image over to Illustrator and traced over the raster image to create 2 separate objects that cover the outline of the floor plan.
3. Exported as svg.
4. Used css to color in the fill and stroke, when each `polygon` is hovered.

You would probably have to do this in Inkscape. Pretty much any vector application should work, as long as you can export it to svg easily.

<sub><sup>This method is more or less how [these types of maps](https://jqvmap.com/) are usually made these days.</sup></sub>

Comment: I used hover in my examples, because it's easier to test, but you could very easily replace it with click functionality.

Comment: I have to admit this is a very neat and nice solution. Thx.

Comment: very stupid question: how do you add the "jquery edge" library to your js code? I tried to add this in the header, but didn't work <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

Comment: @trilolil I wouldn't use a cdn link like that leads to the "edge version" indefinitely. "Edge" means it's the latest version of jquery. If you do that, the latest file will keep on changing, until at some point your code would stop working (maybe), or there could be other unwanted changes. You could try this google hosted one to the current latest version (3.1.0): `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` . You can always host the file yourself too, and link to it like any other file.

Comment: Tried your link, but unfortunately doesn't work: http://imgur.com/a/CR7vk

Comment: or the jsfiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/00vd2p4x/1/

Comment: @trilolil I don't see anything that would indicate a problem in your imgur link. Could you check a browser console to see if it gives you any errors? What's with the jsfiddle? Works for me.

Comment: yes on jsfiddle everything works fine. But when I run the exact jsfiddle code locally, the jQuery code doesn't work anymore. I copy pasted "my" code in jsfiddle.

Comment: I am using firefox on linux mint.

Comment: @trilolil I tried your jsfiddle code locally and it also worked just fine. Did you check the console to see if it tells you anything? I have a feeling your swap.js file can't be located and that's the problem.

Comment: There were two errors. 1) swap.js indeed coulnd t be located
2) I had to add the <meta charset="UTF-8"> tag, he didn't interprete the link to the library correctly.
Strange thing is that when I added the tag it immediately worked. Afterwards I removed it and somehow now the browser knows which charset is needed and I don't need to specify it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in GIMP and, as far as I know, in any raster graphics editor. None of PNG, JPEG, GIF, WEBP formats can hold image that is not in rectangular shape. And the web browsers could not handle this.

However, it can be done in [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) after you export the image. Do you (or your webmaster) have access to the source code? Or you use Blogger, WordPress or Tumblr etc.?

**EDIT**: According to your taskbar, you can edit the source ;) Have a look at [HTML `<map>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp). I recommend using `<area shape="poly">`.